# File Vault decryption paused, switch to external?

Tags: encryption, filevault

I have an old MacBook Pro that was running super sloooow. I decided to upgrade to an SSD. The original drive was encrypted, so I wanted to decrypt before I cloned the drive. I think that's where I made a mistake. I should have removed the drive and hooked it to my other Mac as an external, but instead I turned off File Vault encryption in the original Mac. It's been 1 week and the decryption is at 8%. I am assuming it's because the old computer is so slow that it is taking this long. Can I shut the computer down, move the drive to an external enclosure, and resume decryption using my other Mac? Will this speed things up? By the way, the drive is HFS Extended Journaled, and both my old machine and new one are running High Sierra. And yes, stupid me, don't have a backup for the old computer data. One last thing, can I use time machine on this partially decrypted drive, then use the backup to create a clone?

Okay, finally figured it out. After several more days with it stuck at 8% I decided to take my chances with a reboot. It rebooted without issues, but after another week was only at 12%. Nuts. BTW you can check the progress by going into terminal and typing (without quotes) "fileutil cs list". What I did next taught me something about how the decryption works. This is what I THINK happened, an expert may know differently. Apparently when you start the decryption, macOS writes data to the drive that identifies it as being in the decryption process, and because it is a decrypt, other macs can read it without the password. I shut down the laptop and removed the partially decrypted drive. I plugged the drive into a dock connected to my well-functioning Mac Pro. The dock started flashing (data transfer), there was no notification of what was happening, but I soon confirmed that my Mac Pro was continuing to decrypt! I didn't even have to type in the drive's password. About 5 hours later the drive was completely decrypted. Again, no notice it was finished, but when I saw the flashing lights stop and checked the disk in Disk Manager, it was decrypted with no errors! I used SuperDuper! to clone the drive to an SSD. Installed the SSD into the laptop and it ran like new. It seems that cloning software should be able to clone an encrypted drive to a non-encrypted drive as long as the encrypted drive is unlocked, will try that if I ever have to do this again.